# How to invert a sql select query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "**attendence**", in this table all the attendance details of the student is saved. Now if a student is given the attendance for today, that student  should not get displayed in the user interface, remaining all student should attendance is not provided should be get displayed.

For instance we have 5 students with Id's 1,2,3,4,5 (this data is coming from **"students"** table).

The faculty logins and give attendance to student 1 and 4 and logouts. Later he logins **(on the same day)** to provide the attendance, now only the student with id 2,3,5 should get displayed instead of all 5 students.

Column Names in attendee table: student_id, faculty_id, attendance_date.

Comment: Try negating your query.

Comment: A basic guide to negation: `!(A && B) = !A || !B`, `!(A || B) = !A && !B`

Comment: sorry to mention the student's data is populating from students table

Comment: @cybermonkey I feel like `SQL` and programming will be difficult without a basic understanding of boolean algebra.